# Why is my gravatar size inconsistent?

Tags: gravatar

The `size` parameter on this gravatar is not being applied consistently. If I specify `s=20`, the size is ignored and the default 80x80 gravatar is used.

https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/56e0b26efe774115fc4ab45d64302167?s=20

[image]

If I provide `s=21`, then the size is applied is expected.

https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/56e0b26efe774115fc4ab45d64302167?s=21

[image]

I only get this behaviour with some gravatars. Others work fine.

Comment: Dave, it looks like I have a similar issue. But, in my case Gravatar returns the default image when I request a picture with s=64. Just I change it to s=63, all works. I see that your link with s=20 works great now for me. Did you change anything in your gravatar profile? thank you

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten I haven't changed anything in my gravatar profile (as far as I can remember). I don't know when this started working again for me :\

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway!